# i am new to krpano i want to add video but i dont know hot to ddo that can anyone suggest me from scratch thank you?

Tags: html, krpano

i am  very hopefull that i got answer from this developer around the world

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help

Answer (score 0):

There is a video player plugin for Krpano. 
Add this to your tour.xml file.

As 3d distorted hotspot:

```
<hotspot name="video"
             url.flash="videoplayer.swf"
             url.html5="videoplayer.js"
             videourl="video.m4v|video.webm"
             posterurl="videoposter.jpg"
             ath="0.0" atv="0.0"
             distorted="true"
             scale="1.0" 
             rx="0.0" 
             ry="0.0" 
             rz="0.0" 
             pausedonstart="false"
             loop="false"
             volume="1.0"
             directionalsound="true"
             range="90.0"
             rangefalloff="1.0"
             outofrangevolume="0.0"
             onvideoready=""
             onvideoplay=""
             onvideopaused=""
             onvideocomplete=""
             onerror=""
             />
```

As a flat layer element on the screen:

```
<layer name="video"
       url.flash="videoplayer.swf"
       url.html5="videoplayer.js"
       videourl="video.m4v|video.webm"
       posterurl="videoposter.jpg"
       align="center" x="0" y="0"
       pausedonstart="false"
       loop="false"
       volume="1.0"
       onvideoready=""
       onvideoplay=""
       onvideopaused=""
       onvideocomplete=""
       onerror=""
       />
```

Please see [here](https://krpano.com/plugins/videoplayer/) in the Krpano documentation for more information on how to control this plugin.